# std::tuple unpack over multiple arguments

Tags: c++

I have a function taking pairs of (argument type, data ptr) as a variadic list (C function). I would like to unpack the tuple into that function as follows:
`foo(TypeIndex<std::tuple_element_t<I, Tuple>>(), &std::get<I>(tuple));`
thus I wrote a following function:

```
template<typename Tuple, size_t ...I>
void doUnpack(Tuple const& tp, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    foo((type<std::tuple_element_t<I, Tuple>>(), std::get<I>(tp))...);
}
```

the only problem is comma operator ignores everything on the left uses the right hand side. Imagine `type<>` function returns 0 for now, so the above evaluates (using input tuple{1,2,3,4,5}) to `foo(1,2,3,4,5)` instead of `foo(0,1, 0,2, 0,3, 0,4, 0,5)`

Is there any way to accomplish this?

---

Code to reproduce:

```
template<typename Tp>
int type() { return 0; }

template<typename ...Args>
void fun(Args&& ...args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args) << std::endl;
}

template<typename Tuple, size_t ...I>
void doUnpack(Tuple const& tp, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    fun((type<std::tuple_element_t<I, Tuple>>(), std::get<I>(tp))...);
}

int main()
{
    doUnpack(std::tuple{1,2,3,4,5}, std::make_index_sequence<5>{});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that the `,` here is parsed as a comma operator, which pretty much ignores its left-hand expression's result, and uses the right-hand expression's; and not the `,` as a function argument separator. Have you considered passing a `std::tuple` of type/value, to your `foo`, instead of having them as discrete parameters? This will neatly sidestep this issue.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The way I see that this looks like the only solution for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following does what you want:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Tp>
int type() {
    return 0;
}

template<typename Tuple, size_t... I>
auto doUnpack(Tuple const &tp, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    auto fun = [](auto &&...args) { (std::cout << ... << args) << std::endl; };
    std::apply(fun, std::tuple_cat(std::pair{type<std::tuple_element_t<I, Tuple>>(), std::get<I>(tp)}...));
}

int main() {
    doUnpack(std::tuple{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, std::make_index_sequence<5>{});
    return 0;
}
```

We use two nice STL-functions. [`std::tuple_cat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat) takes a bunch of tuples (here pairs of the type and the value of the tuple) and concatenates them to one big tuple. So you go from `(type0, val0), (type1, val1)...` to `(type0, val0, type1, val1, ...)`. This goes around the problem with the comma operator. After that, we apply the function to that with [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply). Note that I use a lambda since `std::apply` needs (basically) a callable with a type and a function template does not qualify for that (whereas a lambda is (basically) a struct with templated `operator()` which works for that.